# Batch file for loop through switch-like arguments?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, dos

I'm trying to loop through the arguments that I am passing to a batch file. Based on the argument, I want to set a variable flag true or false for use later in the script

So my command is "myscript.bat /u /p /s"

And my code is:

```
FOR /f %%a IN ("%*") DO (
  IF /I "%%a"=="/u" SET UPDATE=Y
  IF /I "%%a"=="/p" SET PRIMARY=Y
  IF /I "%%a"=="/s" SET SECONDARY=Y
)
```

It only works if i have a single argument, which tells me that it is getting the entire list of arguments as a single argument. I've tried "delims= " but to no avail. Any thoughts on getting each spaced argument?

---

What about adding a value to one of the params?

myscript.bat /u /p /d TEST /s

```
:loop
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO cont
IF /I "%~1"=="/u" SET UPDATE=Y
IF /I "%~1"=="/p" SET PRIMARY=Y
IF /I "%~1"=="/s" SET SECONDARY=Y
IF /I "%~1"=="/d" SHIFT & SET DISTRO="%~1"
SHIFT & GOTO loop

:cont
```

But the SHIFT that comes inline with the last IF doesn't actually shift anything. DISTRO ends up being "/d" instead of "TEST"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could loop over the arguments using SHIFT, GOTO and an extra IF to check if there are no more parameters to parse:

```
:loop
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO cont
IF /I "%~1"=="/u" SET UPDATE=Y
IF /I "%~1"=="/p" SET PRIMARY=Y
IF /I "%~1"=="/s" SET SECONDARY=Y
SHIFT & GOTO loop

:cont
...
```

---

**UPDATE** (addressing the case when a parameter has an argument of its own)

The SHIFT in the IF statement that checks for `/d` does work. The issue is that the entire line is evaluated at once and both instances of `%~1` get replaced with the same value, which is `/d` at that point.

So, basically the solution in this case would be to cause the interpreter to evaluate the `SET DISTRO="%~1"` part separately from the `IF /I "%~1"=="/d"`. There can be various approaches to this. For instance, you could simply move `SHIFT & SET DISTRO="%~1"` to the next line and skip it if `%~1` is *not* `/d`:

```
...
IF /I NOT "%~1"=="/d" GOTO skip_d
SHIFT & SET "DISTRO=%~1"
:skip_d
...
```

Another method could be to assign a special value (e.g. a `?`) to `DISTRO` and shift when `/d` is encountered. Then, on the next line, check if `DISTRO` has that special value and set it to `%~1`:

```
...
IF /I "%~1"=="/d" SHIFT & SET DISTRO=?
IF "%DISTRO%"=="?" SET "DISTRO=%~1"
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 24):

You're not too far off on your original piece, and since I dislike GOTO loops, I thought I'd post this:

```
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
  IF /I "%%a"=="/u" SET UPDATE=Y
  IF /I "%%a"=="/p" SET PRIMARY=Y
  IF /I "%%a"=="/s" SET SECONDARY=Y
)
```

The reason it was only working with one parameter is the over-use of quotes. By putting %* in quotes you were making the entire commandline one single token. also, the /F variant of FOR isn't what you were looking for either. The documentation available from FOR /? should help clear things up.