# Batch File arbitrary command-line arguments

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-line-arguments, batch-processing

I want the program to process an arbitrary number of command-line arguments, but I'm unsure how to implement a for loop to go through multiple shift commands. Also, the program shouldn't close the command prompt window when it ends.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto skip
if "%1"=="-ti" time /t
if "%1"=="-da" date /t
if "%1"=="-c" cls
if "%1"=="-ip" ipconfig
if "%1"=="-d" dir
if "%1"=="-p" path
if "%1"=="-v" ver
if "%1"=="-t" type
if "%1"=="-m" md
exit /b
:skip
echo No arguments!
```

I'd like to have the following command-line arguments run properly:

```
C:\>batchfile –d –ti –da –ip –v
C:\>batchfile
C:\>batchfile –d –m CSC3323 –d
C:\>batchfile –d –t batchfile.bat –m CSC3323 –d
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file for loop through switch-like arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247636/batch-file-for-loop-through-switch-like-arguments)

Comment: This is hard to do in Cmd.exe shell script (batch file) code. I would strongly recommend PowerShell, which has fancy parameter parsing built right in. This article will give you an introduction - [Windows IT Pro - PowerShell: Why You'll Never Go Back to Cmd.exe Batch Files](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/powershell-why-youll-never-go-back-cmdexe-batch-files).

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to loop through your arguments in a file called batchfile.bat:

```
@echo off
echo arguments: "%*"
:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto skip
if "%~1"=="-ti" time /t
if "%~1"=="-da" date /t
if "%~1"=="-c" cls
if "%~1"=="-ip" ipconfig
if "%~1"=="-d" dir
if "%~1"=="-p" path
if "%~1"=="-v" ver
if "%~1"=="-t" type
if "%~1"=="-m" md
shift
goto loop
:skip
echo No arguments!
pause
```

and call the batchscript like this:

```
start batchfile.bat -ti -d -ti -da -ip -v 
start batchfile.bat
start batchfile.bat -d -m CSC3323 -d 
start batchfile.bat -d -t batchfile.bat -m CSC3323 -d
```

Comment: Why using `start`? and I guess you, or better the OP, forgot `"%~1"` the `type` command...